# Change inheritance of a class which inherits from a different class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have a class (B) which inherits from another class (A). Now I want to change it so that class (B) inherits from a different class (C). Class B comes from another python package which I have installed but do not want to edit directly in the source. How can I do this without re-writing the entire code for the class (B).

E.g.

```
# Contents of a file contained in different package which I have installed
# We will call it source.py

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('A')


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def sum():
        return 5+5
```

```
# Here is the contents of a file I am writing locally
from source import A, B

class C():
    def __init__(self):
        print('C')

# This is the class I'm not sure how to write the inheritance for. 
# Essentially I want B_2 to inherit from B, but in this case I don't
# want B to inherit from A anymore, but from C instead. So the behaviour
# I would want is that if I create an object of the B_2 class, it will print
# 'C' during the init, and also have the .sum() function available
class B_2():
    pass
```

Comment: Sounds like you just want multiple inheritance.  `class B_2(B, C)`.

Comment: `class B_2(C, B)`, that is.

Comment: But if `C.__init__` doesn't use `super`, then `B.__init__` won't be called. If it *does* use `super`, then `A.__init__` will still be called, just after `C.__init__`.

Comment: In general, you can't just "replace" a base class like this.